# How to remove a commit in git that has no specified branch?

Tags: git, version-control

I have the following git repo structure:

```
a-b-c-d-.. [master]
    \
     x
```

The commit x was accidentially done (can't figure out how) and has no named branch. How can I delete this commit?

For detail, git log shows this (Translated back from german, sorry for any inconvieniances):

```
Author: ...
Parents: 8444..
Branch:
Follows up:
Preceding:

...
```

The commit was not removable via `git prune`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If x isn't in any branch's history, and isn't checked out, it will automatically be removed by git sooner or later.  You can look at `git help gc` if you want to remove it right away.  Setting `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable` to zero and then doing `git gc --prune=now` will probably do the trick.

`git rebase`, `git commit --amend`, and other such commands leave these kind of leftovers all the time; git is usually decent enough at dealing with them that you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: This is also very usefull. But I've not enough reputation to vote your answer up, sorry.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Don't know what Ashish is talking about.

Comment: From what I understood (from a comment that no longer exists) the `X` actually **did** belong to a branch. Otherwise, yes, the garbage collection takes care of it. Linus has stressed on its importance a lot.

Comment: OK. Does `git gc --aggressive` work? I've changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`git prune` will do what you want, but it will delete *all* unreachable objects, not just a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Run `git gc` aggressively. May take time.

```
git gc --aggressive
```

More on `git gc` [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html).

Comment: x isn't a branch, it's rather a single commit.

Comment: A branch can have only one commit. `C` and `X` have followed different paths, right?

Comment: @FUZxxl: Since one of your older comments does not exist (which created some confusion), let me confirm, `X` actually *does not* belong to a branch?

Comment: The `--prune` option is on by default.

Comment: @Ashish: Yes. gitk says, that there is no branch, all header fields in the commit info are empty except parent (As added above).